# Checkmark disappears when returning to tableview

Tags: swift, tableview, checkmark

I have a static cell table view with no segue. This is the same as iPhones Setting->Sounds->Text Tones. There's no problem implementing the checkmark and playing that system sound from another ViewController. When returning to the sound setting ViewController there is no checkmark. I am saving the indexPath.row and indexPath.section in the user defaults. I am retrieving this and storing them in variables. How do I use these variables that now have the indexPath "one for row and one for section" to indicate the row that was previously selected. I have tried the solution on the web, videos and StackoverFlow and i just can't seem to get this.

```
var rowSelected:Int = 0
var rowSection:Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if let soundIsNotNill  = defaults.objectForKey("rowSelectedKey") as? Int{
        self.rowSelected   = defaults.objectForKey("rowSelectedKey") as! Int}

    if let soundIsNotNill  = defaults.objectForKey("rowSectionKey") as? Int{
        self.rowSection    = defaults.objectForKey("rowSectionKey") as! Int}

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    println(" VDL rowSelected \(rowSelected)")
    println(" VDL rowSection \(rowSection)")

}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 13
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let tappedItem  = indexPath.row
        rowSelected = tappedItem
    let section     = indexPath.section
        rowSection  = section

    for row in 0..<13 {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: section)) {
               cell.accessoryType = row == tappedItem ? .Checkmark : .None
        }
    }



    println("didSelectRow rowSelected \(rowSelected)")
    println("didSelectRow rowSection \(rowSection)")

    var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setObject(section, forKey: "rowSectionKey")
        defaults.setObject(tappedItem, forKey: "rowSelectedKey")
        defaults.synchronize()

    saveSound()
}
```

Comment: I see how the restorationIdentifier works but not sure how to implement  it in the above ViewController. I am new at this. I there a way to use the table view cell identifier to tell the tableview "willDisplayCell" or the appropriate "tableView(tableView: UITableView" to use the row and section that is saved in the variables to add the checkmark back?

Answer (score 0):

One way to preserve the table's selection state is to give it a restoration identifier string. You can do this either by setting the table view's `restorationIdentifier` property, or setting it in the table's identity inspector in Interface Builder.